# How to resolve a "Too many arguments" error?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I get the Too many arguments problem in this line:

```
stoch = ta.stoch(close, high, low, stochK, stochD)
```

Is there a way to fix it without putting away variables?

Unfortunately, I was not able to find any info in the internet about this.

Comment: Please check docs: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}stoch